# HTML: Best way to add event listener(s) to a matrix of elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

Let's say I have a dynamically built matrix (using `tr`s and `td`s)

```
----------------------
1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5
----------------------
6  | 7  | 8  | 9  | 10
----------------------
11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15
----------------------
```

I want to `alert` the number that's clicked.

I don't want to add an event listener for every `td` or set an event listener on `table` and read from `event.target` properties. Basically I don't want to rely on the DOM for this.

What's the best way to achieve this in terms of runtime performance and space, given the constraints. Below is something I tried.

```js
function createTable() {
  var table = document.createElement('table'),
    cells = '',
    rows = '',
    i,
    j

  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
      cells += '<td>' + ((50 * i) + (j + 1)) + '</td>'
    }

    rows += '<tr>' + cells + '</tr>'
    cells = ''
  }

  table.innerHTML = rows
  table.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var cellIndex = event.path[0].cellIndex,
      rowIndex = event.path[1].rowIndex

    alert(50 * rowIndex + (cellIndex + 1))
  })

  document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', table)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createTable)
```

Comment: where do you want to add the event listener?

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't have a specific requirement in terms of attaching the event listener. Just seeking an implementation that has the best performance (time and space) for this use case.

Comment: at least, you need a single event listener, bcause this is the obly way to capture an event.

Comment: Yes, I get it. In that case, do you think my snippet is the best I can get in terms of time and space performance?